# System.InvalidOperationException: Value Dispose() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose

In my windows forms app clients sometimes report a strange exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Value Dispose() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at MyCompany.SomeApp.DialogBox.Show(string caption, string message)
   at MyCompany.SomeApp.MainForm.Button1_Click(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

The code that causes this error looks like this:

```
namespace MyCompany.SomeApp
{
    public class DialogBox : CustomForm
    {
        public static DialogResult Show(string caption, string message)
        {
            using (DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox())
            {
                dialog.Text = caption;
                dialog.lblMessage.Text = message;
                return dialog.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

DialogBox is basically a class that inherits from Windows.Forms.Form and does some design changes, nothing special. The excepions happens at

```
return dialog.ShowDialog();
```

and not at the end of the `using` block as I would expect. It looks like somehow, within the `ShowDialog()` method and before the form's handle is created, the Dispose() method is called.
But my DialogBox neither calls Dispose() itself nor swallows other exceptions, it only does some painting in the OnPaint() event.

Does anybody have some clues how to get rid of this exception?

Update:

Here is the only code in my CustomForm class (besides changes mode in the windows forms designer (added 2 Labels, a button and changed some colors)

```
Public Class CustomForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    <DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Static pen1 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(39, 46, 54), 21)
        Static pen2 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(44, 51, 59), 1)
        Static pen3 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(93, 99, 99), 1)
        Static pen4 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(119, 124, 127), 1)
        Static pen5 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(148, 157, 156), 1)
        Static pen6 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(175, 185, 186), 1)

        With e.Graphics
            .DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, (Me.Width - 1), (Me.Height - 1))
            .DrawLine(pen1, 1, 11, Me.Width - 1, 11)
            .DrawLine(pen2, 1, 22, Me.Width - 2, 22)
            .DrawLine(pen3, 1, 23, Me.Width - 2, 23)
            .DrawLine(pen4, 1, 24, Me.Width - 2, 24)
            .DrawLine(pen5, 1, 25, Me.Width - 2, 25)
            .DrawLine(pen6, 1, 26, Me.Width - 2, 26)
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = (-16)
    Private Const WS_CAPTION As Integer = &HC00000
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
             (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property HasCaption() As Boolean
        Get
            return (GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL_STYLE) And WS_CAPTION) = WS_CAPTION
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Update: I changed the code a little bit because it was misleading.
In the stacktrace you can see that My.App.DialogBox.Show(...) is called. Which is a static method that contains the using block.
Neither DialogBox nore CustomForm override the ShowDialog() method of Form (which is why it is not shown in the stacktrace.

Comment: Please post the literal code. This is going nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I found a clou here: http://softwareinvent.com/wordpress/?p=10

> I kept getting an odd exception today:
>
> Value Dispose() cannot be called while
>   doing CreateHandle()
>
> I couldn’t figure out what was causing
>   it until I started commenting out
>   large swaths of code (gotta love brute
>   force debugging  ).  It all came down
>   to a very innocent looking line of
>   code:
>
> ```
> if (Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
> ```
>
> This line of code grabs an unmanaged
>   Windows handle. As a result, that
>   handle must be manually cleaned up

Looks exactly like my problem. Maybe some weired threading issue in which, in rare conditions the HasCaption property is called exactly at the same time as the property HasCaption gets queried.

Comment: The supplied link is broken.

Comment: @kerem That's why I always try to quote the most relevant part as I already did :-)

Comment: @JakeSmith Look at the question `return (GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL_STYLE) And WS_CAPTION) = WS_CAPTION` The exception occures because `Handle` is accessed in an unsafe manner. You could query `IsHandleCreated` or set a flag yourself to avoid this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Start by breaking it up, because now you can't tell if it's this using block or a Dispose inside the Dialog.

The following will be much more informative in the debugger:

```
using (DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox())
{
    dialog.Text = caption;
    var r = dialog.ShowDialog();
    return r;
}
```

### Edit

I find this line in the error message

> at My.App.DialogBox.Show()

hard to reconcile with

```
return dialog.ShowDialog();
```

So, is the error happening with .Show() or .ShowDialog() ?

Comment: He posted a C# code snippet but the stack trace shows stuff that could only appear in a VB.NET app.  Note the My namespace.  Making it impossible to diagnose his problem of course.

Comment: I tried to shorten the code / stack to only show the interesting parts, now I fixed that. `First`: More detailed code, ShowDialog() is called in a static method of my DialogBox class that is (unfortunately) called Show(string, string). `Second`: I lied to you as I said my class inherits from Form, it inherits from another class that itself inherits Form. Now I updated my code. `Third`: I never use the My namespace, I accidently changed my employers namespace to something starting with My in this example. Sorry for this uncertainty.

Comment: OK. And did you try to break the return statment?

Comment: Jepp, but that can take one or two weeks to get a new stacktrace. However I think I found a something related to the problem (posted an answer with the link).

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this exception off and on while running unit tests. Turns out it was a threading issue. Depending on timing, another thread was attempting to modify a GUI control while the main test thread was tearing down and disposing of the form that contained the control.

I changed the unit test to wait for all expected GUI updates (even though that wasn't what was being tested) before exiting and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Your fix doesn't sound like the right way to fix this...WinForms applications should be marshalling all UI calls to the thread that created that UI component.  If you try to access it from the wrong thread, you are opening yourself up to CrossThreadExceptions...

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old question. But if someone's interested in, this is my solution.

```
    `Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 1000;
    tmr.Tick += tmrTick;
    tmr.Start();
    void tmrTick(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        Timer tmr = sender as Timer;
        tmr.Stop();
        Form.Close(); //Form is form which wants to close by instance name. for example: this.Close()
    }`
```

Maybe there are some wrong syntax cause translating Vb to c# by myself. Sorry for this.
But it must be nearly like this by c#.